# Is there a way to see progress for an R function or speed it up?

Tags: r, function, performance, resources

So I built a function in R which is shown below

```
get_means <- function(x){
  as.data.frame(read.table(x)) %>%
    separate(col = V3, into = c("end position", "Methylation"), sep = "\\|") %>%
    mutate(Methylation = ifelse(Methylation == "NAN", "0", Methylation),
           Methylation = as.numeric(Methylation)) %>%
    group_by(V1) %>%
    summarise(across(everything(), list(mean)))
}
```

Essentially the function finds the average for a variable of interest across many files of interest. The function has worked previously for 100+ files with each file being around 5MB. Now I'm trying to run this same function on 100+ files with each file being around 500MB. So as expected its taking a long time to process but I just can't help but wonder if there's a way to check for progress (besides the red STOP sign on the top right of the R console). Also if it takes any longer any suggestions to make it happen faster if I stop it and restart the function. For background I'm using an Apple laptop (2020 i5 model) to run R version 4.1.0

The function is run on all the files using the below code if interested

```
List_Means <- lapply(files, get_means)
```

My hope is that if there's someway to optimize the process, I'll be able to run it overnight while closing everything else on my laptop. I looked at a few ways to increase resource allocation but wasn't sure if it would make a difference so I wanted some additional feedback on what the best way to speed up an R process is and whether there's anyway to have some sort of progress meter that shows X number of files have been processed out of 100 files.

Thanks

Comment: You could simply print x at the start of your function to show the file you are working on, but yes, there are progress meters available in R, which are easily found with a bit of Googling or searching here on SO

Comment: If you have many groups in `V1`, you should get a big performance speedup (potentially 10-100x) from using `data.table` or `collapse` for the summarization. Both have wrappers (`dtplyr` in the case of `data.table`, or built-in options for `collapse`) so that you don't even need to rewrite your code.  https://sebkrantz.github.io/collapse/articles/collapse_and_dplyr.html

Answer (score 1):

You could try this `data.table` aproach.
This should have much faster reading of files and faster calculation of group means.

```
get_means2 <- function(x) {
  library(data.table)
  dt <- fread(x)
  cat('file', x, 'read \n')
  dt <- dt %>%
    separate(col = V3, into = c("end position", "Methylation"), sep = "\\|")
  
  dt[, Methylation := as.numeric(ifelse(Methylation == "NAN", "0", Methylation))]
  dt[, `end position` := as.numeric(`end position`)]
  dt[, lapply(.SD, mean), keyby = V1]
}
```

Also, you can add `cat` function for some printing to console. For example I added that we print out name of file read.